# Universal Android Media Player - UAMP

Tags: android, media-player, playback

I'm using the Universal Android Media Player sample as the basis of another app. For the love of me I cannot figure out how to update the MusicProvider the MusicService uses (ie. change the songs in the queue).
This is to be done when the user clicks on a random item - the service will be provided with a new list to play from.

Any ideas? - the original source is located here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

I've already created the new MusicProvider, how do I get that to the service is what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to modify the **model/RemoteJSONSource.java** so that it adds *MediaMetadataCompat* items into the **tracks** ArrayList.

You will need to create a '*buildFromJSON*' method that creates a **MediaMetadataCompat** object.  Be sure to set as many of the media attributes as possible.

The Google example shows media being added from a remote JSON source.
In my case, I have already loaded remote Firebase JSON into a local SQLite
database. So I load my media from SQLite instead. To do that I modified the
*buildFromJson* to be *buildFromEpisodesCursor* and changed the guts appropriately. (Firebase can send JSON updates to SQLite if the media changes.)  Here is a snippet with the key codeblocks:

```
public class RemoteJSONSource implements MusicProviderSource {

    @Override
    public Iterator<MediaMetadataCompat> iterator() {
        ArrayList<MediaMetadataCompat> tracks = new ArrayList<>();
        EpisodesCursor episodesCursor = getEpisodes();
        if (episodesCursor != null) {
            while (episodesCursor.moveToNext()) {
                tracks.add(buildFromEpisodesCursor(episodesCursor));
            }
            episodesCursor.close();
        }
        return tracks.iterator();
    }

    private MediaMetadataCompat buildFromEpisodesCursor(EpisodesCursor episodesCursor) {

        // INITIALIZE THE VARIOUS MEDIA DATA ITEMS YOU NEED HERE (ommitted)

        MediaMetadataCompat theMetadata = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, id)
                .putString(MusicProviderSource.CUSTOM_METADATA_TRACK_SOURCE, episodeDownloadUrl)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, episodeTitle)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, artist)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_WRITER, episodeWriter)
                .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, duration)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DATE, airdate)
                .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_YEAR, airdate_year)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_GENRE, genre)
                .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, iconBitmap)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, iconUrl)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE, episodeTitle)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, episodeTitle)
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION, episodeDescription)
                .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER, episodeNumber)
                .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_NUM_TRACKS, totalTrackCount)
                .putRating(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_RATING, ratingCompat)
                .build();

        return theMetadata;
    }

    ...

}
```

uTube videos with the key patterns:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIKxyDRjecU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQwe30cZffg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBC1FgWe5X4&utm_campaign=adp_series_mediabrowserservicecompat_030116&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog